# Maven run all spring & angular modules at once

Tags: maven, spring-boot, maven-module

I want to run this project: [github](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/tree/master/oauth2)

How can I run all modules of this project (Angular & 2xSpring Boot) at once and test this in the browser?

I dont know how to start this. When I'm running these spring projects separately by `mvn spring-boot:run` and ui by `ng s` then it's just not working.

Comment: Maybe it could interest you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913909/angular-and-spring-boot-configuration-to-make-them-work-together-efficiently