# Whitelabel Error Page just type on URL?

Tags: spring, angular, spring-boot, url, angular-routing

This **Spring-boot** project is integrated with **Angular 4**. I can reach the home page when type the url adress >> `localhost:8080`.

I get *whitelabel error page* when type any diffent url is added parameter like: */login, /signup*.

> There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).

I can reach these pages (`localhost:8080/signup`, `localhost:8080/foo`, ..) on website using **angular-routing**. So the problem is about only hitting url directly.

So How can I solve this, any idea to check would be helpful.

**Note**: There is no authorization for these url in server side.

Edit: index.html path added.

```
src/main/resources
  static
    assets
    index.html
    bundle
    bundle
    ..
```

**routing.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path:'signup',
    component: SignupComponent,
    canActivate: [GuestGuard],
    pathMatch:'full'
  },
```

Comment: can you send angualar-routing file code?

Comment: Either you configure your server to return a FallBack page or Use [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles)

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented directly this `WebMvcConfigurer` and it works perfectly for me. This is the reference [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46854105/3222918).

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.PathResourceResolver;

@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {

      registry.addResourceHandler("/**/*")
        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
        .resourceChain(true)
        .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
            @Override
            protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath,
                Resource location) throws IOException {
                Resource requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);
                return requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable() ? requestedResource
                : new ClassPathResource("/static/index.html");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: where you have the `/static/index.html` in the Spring or Angular project ?

Comment: It was integrated with angular

Answer (score 1):

Create a controller and forward every request to index.html as follows,

```
@RequestMapping({  "/signup", "/purchase", "/credit"})
public String index() {
    return "forward:/index.html";
}
```

By doing this, angular will pickup the url and navigate to the corresponding pages. Also please modify the request urls as needed. Whenever a request is hit from browser directly, it will pickup by the spring boot and spring boot doesnt know the angular routing urls. To prevent this we need to forward all request to index.html.

Or you can use the Use [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles) as @Vikas suggested

Comment: Thanks, I will try this solution

Comment: Doing so will override all static resources handling, and browsing to "/does-not-exist" will never respond with an HTTP 404.

Comment: @BrianClozel you are right that is why i mentioned 'Also please modify the request urls as needed.'. We need to put the root urls of the angular application. for example /signUp, /login etc

Comment: @AntoAntony I have tried this solution and it didn't work for me. `index.html` is under **resources/static** path. Moreover this solution make every url request with params direct the home page.

Comment: @krezus it will work. Please try to add the root paths of your angular projects manually. if you go for /** then it will redirect everything to index.html

Comment: @AntoAntony this returns a html page written `forward:/index.html`  and I want to reach the signup page from browser directly not want to go home page or index html.

Comment: @krezus is this signup page is part of angular application or a spring web application? if its the part of angular, you can forward the requests to index.html and  angular will redirect to the signup page

Comment: Actually I dont understand clearly. Yes it is part of angular side.Correct me if I misunderstood  You said that when I forward or direct these requests (/signup) to index html, angular will do redirect to signup ? If yes how ? what I need to add angular side? @AntoAntony

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171697/discussion-between-anto-antony-and-krezus).