# Angular + Spring Boot: Forwarding all Angular routes to Angular and all API to the Spring Controllers

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a Spring Boot app and an Angular app. I want to serve the Angular App from the Spring Boot App. I build the Angular App and moved all files, including the index.html file, into /resources/static/ and just to be sure also to resources/public/. I also put the index.html into resources/templates.
I received 404 when calling any of the angular routes e.g. mywebsite.com/login

Then I added a controller to forward all requests to my Angular App:

```
@Controller
public class RedirectToAngularController {

  /**
  * Should redirect all routes to FrontEnd, but doesn't work.
  */
  @RequestMapping({"/", "/login", "/login/**"})
  public String redirectLogin() {
    log.info("Forwarding request to Angular (index.html)");
    return "forward:/index.html";
  }
}
```

IntelliJ gives me a warning for "forward:/index.html" that it can't find the URL:

[image: warning]

I still deployed my website and open it at `myWebsite.com/login` or `myWebsite.com/confirm`. Instead of my index.html file getting displayed I see `forward:/index.html` as a string in my browser. So it actually returns the string, not the file
In the logs "Forwarding request to Angular (index.html)" appears, but then it says: `Cannot find GET /index.html` in the next line.

So I deleted that controller and instead tried to solve this with a ResourceHandler:

```
@Configuration
public class WebAdapterConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/**/*")
              .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
              .resourceChain(true)
              .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
                @Override
                protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
                  Resource requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);

                  return requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable() ? requestedResource
                          : new ClassPathResource("/static/index.html");
                }
              });
    registry.setOrder(-1);
  }
}
```

This was described here: [Springboot/Angular2 - How to handle HTML5 urls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38516667/springboot-angular2-how-to-handle-html5-urls)
and also here: https://keepgrowing.in/java/springboot/make-spring-boot-surrender-routing-control-to-angular/

But this redirects everything! I now get the index file when I open mywebsite.com/login as well as when I make a postman request to my api (e.g. GET mywebsite.com/api/users)

So I tried to narrow it down by replacing `registry.addResourceHandler("/**/*")` with `registry.addResourceHandler("/login")` or `registry.addResourceHandler("/login/**", "/confirm")`. But then only mywebsite.com/login/something and mywebsite.com/confirm retrun the index.html, but all other paths, including the URI for the api methods return 404!

A third approach was to add view controller:

```
@Configuration
public class WebAdapterConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

  @Override
  public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
    registry.addViewController("/login/**").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
    registry.addViewController("/confirm").setViewName("forward:/index.html");
  }
}
```

But then I always received 404 for all routes.

I also added spring web MVC to my dependencies, but this didn't seem to change anything.

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
}
```

p.s. I don't use tymeleaf as my files are coming from angular. Maybe that's why `forward:/` doesn't work?

Comment: same issue - I believe you are also trying out the tutorial from bbachi https://github.com/bbachi/angular-java-example

Comment: Hey, could be, I don't quite remember it anymore. I solved the issue but it's a long time ago, but what I could find in my code / remembered I have posted as answer now. Good luck!

Comment: I got the fix from another stackoverflow page, remove the default path "/" forwarding completely from code, make sure @EnableWebMVC annotation is not used and your Single Page Application (index.html) files are kept in "resources/public" path. SpringBoot automatically handles it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Make sure no default path "/" is configured in your SpringBoot code/controller's
2. Ensure you are not using @EnableWebMvc annotation anywhere in your app
3. put all your UI files in the "../resources/public" folder (mainly your index.html shall be on this path)

This should resolve your issue's in general :)

SpringBoot automatically detects this and works well for all sorts of Single-page applications.

Answer (score 0):

Narrowing down the ResourceHandler paths was the right approach:

```
registry.addResourceHandler(
        "/login/**",
        "/all other Uris of my website"
).addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
 .resourceChain(true)
 .addResolver(new PathResourceResolver() {
   @Override
   protected Resource getResource(String resourcePath, Resource location) throws IOException {
              Resource requestedResource = location.createRelative(resourcePath);

              return requestedResource.exists() && requestedResource.isReadable() ? requestedResource
                      : new ClassPathResource("/static/index.html");
            }
          });
```

There was another problem that kept returning 404 for the other URIs, but that had nothing to do with the resourceHandler, but was a problem at our Gateway.